# d3 force directed layout, bounding boxes based on data-type

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bounding-box

I have a force directed layout in d3. In my network visualizations, I have unique data-types for each sector in the network. How can I make it so that I compute bounding boxes for each individual data-type instead of for the whole visualization?

Here is where I'm setting up my bounding box. Also I need to set up a separate bounding box for each sector, not just for the Federal nodes.

```
    force.on("tick", function () {

    if ("[data-type]" === "Federal") {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(200, Math.min(width - 0, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(20, Math.min(height - 10, d.y)); });      
    } {return}

    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});
```

});

Here is my full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/QZ8chcsOj64oYJnIqz1J

Comment: You want each of Non-Governmental Organization, Academia, Commonwealth of Virginia, etc... constrained to it's own box so it can't be dragged and intermixed?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. Except I am trying to allow for the user to scroll through each of the constrained boxes rather than being able to drag them around.

Comment: any luck with this? i'm trying to do something similar